# Does any language using the Latin alphabet have a unique name for "w"?

Tags: orthography, phonemes

In English, we call `w` "double-u", referring to the original representation of [w], which looked like `uu`, or two `u`s. Then, in French, they pronounce it "double-veh", presumably because the modern form looks like two `v`s or "veh".

The question is: do all languages which utilise the Latin alphabet do a similar thing, giving a name to the letter which refers to either the letters `u` or `v`? Or the converse question: is there any language which has a unique name for `w`, whose etymology is not linked to another letter in any recognisable way?

Comment: Yes, the letter <w> is pronounced /we/ in German, which is not derived from either <u> /?u/ or <v> /fau/.

Comment: To the down-voter, is this question off-topic?

Comment: Originally there was no difference between "U" and "V" in the Latin alphabet. When "w" was invented, it was indeed a doubled form of that letter, hence some languages call it "double u" yet others "double v".

Comment: @JoePineda didn't the sound /w/ exist before w's invention?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc of course it did, in Latin at least. Emperor Claudius, being the keen amateur linguist he was, readily noticed that slight ambiguity in Latin's spelling (having same letter for both "u" and "w" sounds) and proposed a new letter, an upside-down "F", to denote the "w" sound. He went on and invented 2 other ones for "bs" and "y" sounds - the last one solving the ambiguity still present in modern Romance spellings of using "i" for both "ee" as in "bee" and "y" as in "young".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- In many Germanic languages it's /ve/, as fdb said

  > In other Germanic languages, including German, its name is similar to that of English V
  >
  > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W#Name
- In Polish it's /vu/. In Italian it's also pronounced as /vu/ in common acronyms for brevity
- In Somali it's /wæʉ̯/

  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/W#Somali

Comment: As stated, Germans and Poles call V /faw/ and W /ve/ and /vu/ respectively, so there is no direct link between them.

Comment: I didn't say there are any relation between German and Polish

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I think Arsen is saying there's no link between the names for <v> and <w>, as specified in the question.

Comment: There's a similar phenomenon to that of Italian in Belgian French, where the usual /dublœve/ is instead /we/ in acronyms. Other French dialects don't do this afaik

Comment: In Welsh, the letter <w> is simply pronounced /u/; there's no ambiguity because <u> is *not* pronounced /u/.

Comment: @MarkBeadles interesting. So is w a vower or consonant in Welsh?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc It's considered a vowel, although it can also be used as a semivowel.

Answer (score 4):

As Robert said, it is /ve/ in German, and thus also in Dutch.

Comment: ...and thus also in Afrikaans!

Comment: It's /we/ in Dutch; /ve/ is the letter V. /w/ may be realised phonetically as [ʋ] in Netherlandic dialects but it still contrasts with /v/.